# phonegap 3.1 - Unable to hide splash screen on device ready

Tags: android, cordova

Using phonegap 3.1 I'm trying to hide the splash screen when device is ready:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
 navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
```

But it returns:

> Cannot call method 'hide' of undefined

The navigator object doesn't including the splashscreen attribute.

I've tried it on phonegap 2.9 and it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After research and experiments this is what we had to do in order to get it work:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen`

`cordova build`

Then, cordova build was adding the wrong lines to the config.xml - So we had to change it to the following:

```
 <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
 </feature>
```

And in your main activity

```
 super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
 super.setIntegerProperty("splashScreenDelay", 10000); //time to display the splash
```

Finally we have been able to use `hide` method from javascript.

Comment: in 3.4 i needed to add the <feature> to the config. why doesnt the CLI do this????

Comment: How would you do this for iOS?

Comment: @Petar Vasilev (in the named application directory's config.xml : `<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>`

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the CLI to add the [SplashScreen plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen)? You have to add the plugin with `$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen` (copy the plugin code from plugins.cordova.io into /yourApp/plugins/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen/ and then later `cordova build` to copy the plugin code into the appropriate platform location.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using phonegap build, rather than doing

```
cordova plugin add ...
```

from the command line, you'll need to add the plugin and feature to the `config.xml`:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can guess is to double check that you have `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>` in the head of your HTML that is calling that JS. Sorry, haven't messed with 3.1 yet.

Comment: I would say the only thing left to do is submit a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash.png" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

The navigator.splashscreen.hide() doesn't work for me either.

**UPDATE:** navigator.splashscreen.hide() only works when building online (phonegap build).

Comment: When stuff only works when building with PGB, it means you have missing plugins on your side. Install the splash screen plugin with `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen` and it should work correctly on your Cordova CLI.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Phonegap Desktop 0.3.6, I had a similar issue and one of my older apps was stuck on the splash screen. In the configuration window, it was showing the correct app name and version and it was updating as soon as I was modifying the config.xml. In the console I had only one error: `500` for `http://localhost:3000/cordova_plugins.js`

A new app was working fine.

I tried all the above:

- splash screen plugin and configuration
- adding the `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugins.js` to `index.html`. This is not necessary anymore since many versions ago - the build does it for you.
- in the `platforms/android/assets/www` folder there were `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugins.js`files present
- in the `config.xml` there was specified `<content src="index.html" />`

In the end what solved my problem was to completely delete the `platforms` folder and run `cordova platform add android` again. I guess it's safe to do this after each Phonegap upgrade.