# PhoneGap 3.1 Splashscreen on Android (4.2, 4.3): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-3

### The issue:

I am facing this issue since I have updated from PhoneGap 3.0.0 to 3.1.0.

```
11-08 15:30:54.997: E/CordovaWebView(32728): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
```

### The Code

I have the following code in my **main Java**:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Splash screen
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);

    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "JSPlugin");
}
```

Relevant part of **Config.xml**:

```
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="splashscreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="splashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

**Index.html** (`onDeviceReady` runs fine, but hide() doesn't make any difference):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
```

### What happens is the following:

The app loads and the *splashscreen* displays but it doesn't hide. So after a while I get the `CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!` and the app crashes. 
On the screen I get an error:

```
Application Error
The connection to the server was unsuccessful.
(javascript:JSPlugin.myFunction('...');)
```

It crashes on both `Android 4.2` and `Android 4.3` but it runs fine on `iOS 6` and `iOS 7`.

### What I have tried is:

- Cordova update `npm install -g cordova`
- Platform update: `cordova platform update android`
- Removing and adding Splashscreen plugin again `cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.splashscreen` and `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen`. Also tried the same with phonegap `phonegap local plugin...`
- After plugin re-install: `cordova build android`
- I tried to remove this line `super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);` from the **main .java** because i have the `Config.xml` preference `<preference name="splashscreen" value="splash" />`. Still crashes.
- **Removing Splashscreen**: if I completely remove the splashscreen preference from `Config.xml` the app loads but obviously without the splashscreen.
- I have tried this as well: [phonegap 3.1 - Unable to hide splash screen on device ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515759/phonegap-3-1-unable-to-hide-splash-screen-on-device-ready)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found out why did this happen. It is very odd because at the end it seems the solution has nothing to do with `SplashScreen`. Still it is only present when `splashscreen` is **enabled**.

I have an `Init()` function which launches `onDeviceReady()`. This `init()` calls a `JAVA` function from `JavaScript`.

The way I was calling JAVA from Javascript was through `@JavascriptInterface`, having `window.JSPlugin.myFunction();` in the JavaScript code. It worked until I have upgraded to **PhoneGap 3.1** but after it crashed.

However this was documented in earlier Cordova / PhoneGap versions the `@JavascriptInterface` and `window.JSPlugin.myFunction()` approach still worked.

The oddest thing is why does only the SplashScreen plugin break this?

#### Solution

is to use the PhoneGap method (which I am using for iOS anyway):

```
cordova.exec(function(){},function(){},'com.myApp.JSPlugin','myFunction()',[]);
```