# phonegap app stuck on splash screen

Tags: cordova

My app working locally in xcode, working in android, and is approved and available in apple shop,

but when I download it form  the apple shop it get stuck in splash screen,

How can I debug it?
or solve it?

Comment: refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515759/phonegap-3-1-unable-to-hide-splash-screen-on-device-ready

Comment: Shuas, the question you refer to is not relevant - in my case the app works, only the version on the apple shop get stuck, is there a way to debug an app that is downloaded from the app store?