# blank screen after splash screen

Tags: android, cordova, google-api

I am using google map service in my application. the map working fine
the problem is when device connect internet through wifi hotspot, in this case 
showing white screen for 5 seconds after splash screen.

When i disable maps.googleapis.com  url, at that time white screen not appear.

I included all permissions in config.xml file, but still getting same  problem.

I included google map service in bellow way.

config.xml file permission as

```
 <access origin="*"/>
<access origin="http://maps.googleapis.com/*"/>
<access origin="*://*.googleapis.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.gstatic.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.google.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.googleusercontent.com/*" subdomains="true" />
```

Comment: device was not ready. thats the reason. try triggering document.ready , you will understand.

Comment: can you explain in detail, i try to include script after page load, but in this case map not working.

Answer (score 0):

try adding console in your script before and after the firing of "deviceready" event. Then you will know that the deviceready event has a timeout of 5 seconds.
you can see the message in the logcat window

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I'm getting message in logcat as, device ready has not fired after 5 seconds. then what i will do next, how to eliminate white screen.

Comment: this may be useful---http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515759/phonegap-3-1-unable-to-hide-splash-screen-on-device-ready

Comment: this is also not working for me, again i'm getting white screen after splash screen. I set splash screen delay time to 5 sec.